# What is wrong with this program? (string related)

Tags: c

I'm trying to find bug in the following program.

If I give input as "This is a test", output shows "This Is A". I'm trying to find out why "Test" is missing.

Please help me to understand the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[1000], word[100];
    int i, j, length, is_word_started;

    gets(str);
    length=strlen(str);
    is_word_started=0;

    for(i=0, j=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')
        {
            if(is_word_started==0)
            {
                is_word_started=1;
                word[j]='A'+str[i]-'a';
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                word[j]=str[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        else if(str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z' || str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9')
        {
            if(is_word_started==0)
            {
                is_word_started=1;

            }
            word[j]=str[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(is_word_started==1)
            {
                is_word_started=0;
                word[j]='\0';
                printf("%s\n", word);
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @usr You should explain [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/613130)

Comment: @usr Sadly "scholastic" C often doesn't include the chapter "how to write safe and secure C code" :-)

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings (don't hide them)  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must repeat the

```
if(is_word_started==1)
{
    is_word_started=0;
    word[j]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", word);
    j=0;
}
```

outside the `for ()` cycle (at the end of its `}`)

Otherwise when you finish parsing the `str`, the letters you were accumulating in `word` are "lost".

Technically you could short it to:

```
if(is_word_started==1)
{
    word[j]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", word);
}
```

because after that you won't reuse those variables.

Other than the "Never use `gets()`" suggested by @usr, you should correctly-size `word`: always use the worst case. If `str[1000]` then `word[1000]`!